# Approach for Master/Parent View with Detail/Child as Partial View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm starting out with **ASP.NET MVC 5**.

Suppose I have the following structure in my project

**'Pure' Models:**

```
class Parent
class Child
```

**Models for Views**

```
class ParentViewModel
class ChildViewModel
```

**Views**

```
Parent<ParentViewModel>
_ChildPartial<ChildViewModel>
```

What is the correct way to pass the child view its model?

Currently, I'm considering the following:

- Let the `ParentViewModel` have a `ChildViewModel` as a property:

```
class ParentViewModel
{
 ...
 ChildViewModel cvm;
 ...
 }
```

- Then, pass the `ChildViewModel` as an argument to the `Partial` view:

```
@model ParentViewModel
...
@Html.Partial("_ChildPartial", new ViewDataDictionary(Model.cvm))
...
```

Is there a more correct way of doing this?

Comment: That's one way to do it. What's _correct_ will depend on your usage and needs. Also, you can just do `@Html.Partial("_ChildPartial", Model.cvm)`.

Comment: Actually, when I tried doing that I got an error; if you don't change the `ViewDataDictionary`, the `Model` property stays with `ParentViewModel` and the framework complains that you're passing in a `ChildViewModel`.

Comment: That does not sound right to me. Unless you are passing the data to the view using the viewdata object. But your approach is good. Well its how i would structure my model and views. Your other option is to user @html.renderaction and generate the child view that way.

Comment: @KevDevMan: `@Html.Action` is in fact a better choice for me.